# How to define shaders as external .glsl files (vertex, fragment) in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/material.html#registering-a-custom-glsl-shader

Currently, we can specify vertex/fragment shaders as strings in `AFRAME.registerShader`. How can I maintain the shaders as separate files so I don't have to code within a long string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way in A-Frame to automatically reference an external shader file. They must be a string right now. It's how three.js shaders are defined, and having them defined within the JS file makes it easier to share and for others to consume without having to referencing several files.

What we can do is use **build tools** though.

Have your vertex and fragment shaders defined in .glsl files...

```
myVertex.glsl
myFragment.glsl
myAFrameShader.js
```

Write your shader like so:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('my-shader', {
  vertexShader: require('./myVertex.glsl'),
  fragmentShader: require(./myFragment.glsl')
});
```

Then install a build tool. **Webpack** works well since it won't throw up when trying to require a .glsl file without configuration. Webpack is a module bundler, which is what we are doing, bundling multiple files into one:

```
npm install -g webpack
npm install --g webpack-glsl-loader
```

Then

```
webpack --module-bind 'glsl=webpack-glsl' myAFrameShader.js output/myAFrameShader.js
```